# Programmatically delete Azure blob storage objects in bulks

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-blob-storage, bulk

Is it possible to programmatically delete Azure blob objects in bulks?
Deleting objects one by one sometimes takes us several days.

We put a lot of new files on the Azure Blob Storage and all the outdated files we want deleted to avoid unwanted charges.

I've googled over the web/[MSDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Developer_Network)/Stack Overflow and found only one topic on MSDN from 2014 that was referring to create feature request on the Microsoft site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to programmatically delete Azure blob objects in bulks?

No. You would need to delete blobs one-by-one.

What you could do to speed up the process is to create different containers (say a container for each year/month combination) and put related blobs in there. When you need to delete the blobs for that month/year, you simply delete that container.

Comment: @EvertonMc What your code is doing is listing the blobs and then sending request to delete the blobs one by one. This is not deletion in bulk IMHO. To me, deletion in bulk would be giving a list of blobs to Azure Storage and have it delete those blobs in one request.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can (i.e. with Powershell)

```
$Ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey
Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container "container-name" -Context $Ctx -Blob TellMeWhatToDelete* | Remove-AzureStorageBlob
```

i.e: This deletes every Powerpoint Presentation in the documents container

```
Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container "documents" -Context $Ctx -Blob *.pptx | Remove-AzureStorageBlob
```

Or you can delete every docx file not changed in the last 30 days

```
Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container "documents" -Context $Ctx -Blob *.docx
| where {$_.LastModified -le (get-date).AddDays(-30) } | Remove-AzureStorageBlob
```

Comment: Okay, but would this really scale to deleting, say, 30M files in bulk? This isn't a hypothetical question. It's what I'm staring at right now.

Answer (score 0):

u can delete blobs in batch. that will be one 1 call.

All you need is :

1. List of URI's for the Blob.
2. Connection to your storage account
3. From package manager add using Azure.Storage.Blobs

in the return, the exception will give you details if there was any issue with deleting the blobs.

> ```
>   BlobServiceClient service = new BlobServiceClient(connectionStringForStorageAccount);
>
>             BlobBatchClient batchClient = service.GetBlobBatchClient();
>             try
>             {
>                   //dont forget to add the include snapshots :)
>                await batchClient.DeleteBlobsAsync(listofURIforBlobs,
>     Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.DeleteSnapshotsOption.IncludeSnapshots);
>
>             }
>             catch (Exception ex)
>             {
>                 return (false, ex.Message);
>             }
> ```