# To delete objects from an Azure Storage Blob in bulk which are 'x' days older

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage

I am looking to delete all files from azure storage blob which are older than 'x' days. I am trying the below code but is not working:

```
$StorageAccountName = '<name>'
$StorageAccountKey = '<key>'

$Ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey
Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container "reports" -Context $Ctx -Blob *.csv
where {$_.LastModified -le (get-date).AddDays(-30) } | Remove-AzureStorageBlob
```

I referred the following doc but the query is not working for conditional deletion. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39471212/programmatically-delete-azure-blob-storage-objects-in-bulks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Ivan. I compared my script with yours and found that I was missing a pipe before the where condition which was issue. After putting the pipe, I am able to delete the files based on condition. Didn't needed to go to AzureAz.
The script which is working now is :

```
$StorageAccountName = 'xx'
$StorageAccountKey = 'yyy'

$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey

Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container "abc" -Blob *.pdf -Context $ctx | where {$_.LastModified -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-4)} | Remove-AzureStorageBlob
```

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you use the new azure powershell module [AZ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-2.2.0).

After install the new AZ module, try the code below:

```
$accountname="xx" 
$accountkey="xxx"
$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $accountname -StorageAccountKey $accountkey

Get-AzStorageBlob -Container "aa1" -Blob *.jpg -Context $ctx | where {$_.LastModified -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)} | Remove-AzStorageBlob
```

After the code running, you can check on azure portal or use `Get-AzStorageBlob` cmdlet to see if all the specified files are deleted. In my case, all the files' date < "1 day ago" are deleted.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Azure storage have feature "Manage the Azure Blob storage lifecycle".
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts

For your test case you can directly refer 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts#powershell

```
$action = Add-AzStorageAccountManagementPolicyAction -BaseBlobAction Delete -daysAfterModificationGreaterThan 2555
```