# How do I delete the old files on Azure blob storage after X amount time using Azure pipelines?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-blob-storage, azure-pipelines-yaml

There is a container on Azure blob storage, I want to automatically delete the files after X amount of time
using Azure pipelines?
Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

There is no out-of-box solution for azure pipelines. You may use the Powershell example from here (add it as a task in your pipeline): [To delete objects from an Azure Storage Blob in bulk which are 'x' days older](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56541817/to-delete-objects-from-an-azure-storage-blob-in-bulk-which-are-x-days-older)

or use the lifecycle management in your account:
[image]